# JasperReports - Specify Allowed Exporters

Tags: export, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I would like to restrict the formats (e.g pdf only) which can be used to export a report created by iReport. Unfortunately I did not find out how to accomplish that. Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What application for building reports are you using (JasperServer or self-programmed application)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it for JasperServer.
You should edit ***`viewReportBeans.xml`*** config file (placed in %JASPER_SERVER_HOME%\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\flows\ folder for my installation with bundled tomcat).

The original block with export options:

```
<util:map id="exporterConfigMap">
    <!-- comment/uncomment any of the lines below if you want related exporters 
         to be excluded/included in the viewer's exporters list -->

    <entry key="pdf" value-ref="pdfExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="xls" value-ref="xlsExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="csv" value-ref="csvExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="docx" value-ref="docxExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="rtf" value-ref="rtfExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="swf" value-ref="swfExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="odt" value-ref="odtExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="ods" value-ref="odsExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="xlsx" value-ref="xlsxExporterConfiguration"/>
    <!-- entry key="txt" value-ref="txtExporterConfiguration"/-->
</util:map>
```

To allow only PDF export you can modify this block like this:

```
<util:map id="exporterConfigMap">
    <entry key="pdf" value-ref="pdfExporterConfiguration"/>
</util:map>
```

Comment: Thanks for that!
Is it also possible to restrict the export options on a per report basis?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I think that it is impossible without deep customization.